# Why is it that without switching to `pgf`, CM fonts are not found by Matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I noticed that I cannot use Computer Modern fonts without loading the backend `pgf`. How come `matplotlib` is able to find CM fonts with `pgf` as backend, but cannot find them when using the default backend? Here is a toy example:

#### With `pgf`

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.switch_backend('pgf')
plt.rc('font',**{'family':'serif', 'serif': ['computer modern roman']})

plt.plot(np.arange(10), np.random.randint(0, 10, 10))
plt.xlabel("Count")
plt.ylabel("Value")
plt.title("Random Plots")

plt.savefig('test.pdf') # Saves figure with CM fonts
```

#### Without `pgf`

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#plt.switch_backend('pgf')
plt.rc('font',**{'family':'serif', 'serif': ['computer modern roman']})

plt.plot(np.arange(10), np.random.randint(0, 10, 10))
plt.xlabel("Count")
plt.ylabel("Value")
plt.title("Random Plots")

plt.savefig('test.pdf') # Warns that font family could not be found:

/home/kartik/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/font_manager.py:1297:
UserWarning: findfont: Font family ['serif'] not found. Falling back to DejaVu Sans
  (prop.get_family(), self.defaultFamily[fontext]))
```

---

Versions:

```
python: 3.6.2.final.0
python-bits: 64
OS: Linux
OS-release: 4.10.0-38-generic
machine: x86_64
processor: x86_64
byteorder: little
LC_ALL: None
LANG: en_US.UTF-8
LOCALE: en_US.UTF-8

pandas: 0.21.0
numpy: 1.13.3
matplotlib: 2.0.2
```

---

Follow-up question: What other backends can find CM fonts?